# SQL query how do I make sure only the criteria in a list are in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to do a query where I want to make sure only the criteria using the list related to the query are in the table.
here is an example table

```
table1
field1|field2
-------------
1     | 2
1     | 3
1     | 4

select * from table1 
where field1 = 1 
and field2 in(2,3)
```

This will return the first 2 records but what I want to do is to test and see if these are the only records where field1 is one.  In this case I would want a query that would somehow return a false result to me.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the results that you would like to get.

Comment: one way is to split into two separate queries  select * from table1 
where field1 = 1 
and select * from table1 
where field2 in (2,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all `field1` values that have a `field2` value in `(2,3)` and no other values?  Just add a NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from table1 
where field1 = 1 
and field2 in(2,3)
and NOT EXISTS
  (
   SELECT null
   FROM table1
   where field1 = 1 
   and field2 NOT in (2,3)
   )
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the overall count of rows `where field1 is 1` and the count of the rows `where field1 is 1 and field 2 is (2,3)`. If the values match then its `TRUE` else `FALSE`

```
Setup:

SELECT * INTO #TBLA FROM (
select 1 field1, 2 field2 UNION ALL
select 1 field1, 3 field2 UNION ALL
select 1 field1, 4 field2 ) A

Query: 
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) - 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN field2 IN (2,3)
                    THEN 1
                END) > 0
        THEN 'false'
    ELSE 'true'
    END FIELD1CNT
FROM #TBLA
WHERE field1 = 1
```

Comment: I thought of the count issue but the count could be the same but the values of field2 could be different.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment? "The count could be the same but the values of field2 could be different"

Comment: You are so right. I made a mistake in my logic.  I can be as smart as Captain Obvious sometimes.